# Excel no puede abrir el archivo 'Prueba.xls' porque el formato o la extensión de éste no son válidos

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Desde hace poco vengo con este problema la cual aun no le doy solucion alguna, tengo una funcion que crea un archivo excel con datos que traigo de una base de datos, el aplicativo a la hora de ser ejecutado de forma local no tiene ningun problema, al momento de montarlo en mi vps (en la nube) esa funcion cae, en un comienzo pense que era de la version del PHP asi que actualize el php de mi servidor al 5.25 y en mi maquina tengo el 5.30, pero sique con ese error.

este es el mensaje de que sale a la hora de descargar de la nube :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es una comparativa :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo dejo el fragmento del codigo:

```
public function exportar_excel_usuarios() {

    ob_start();
    set_time_limit(0);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
    $fecha_reporte = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $lista = null;
    $lista = $this->Usuario_model->listar_reporte();

    $this->load->library('excel');
    $hoja = $this->excel->getActiveSheet();
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $hoja->setTitle('ASUNTOS');
    $hoja->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE DE USUARIOS ' . $fecha_reporte);
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(24);
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $hoja->mergeCells('A1:G1');
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

    $cabecera_columna = array(
        'APELLIDOS',
        'NOMBRES',
        'NUM. DOC.',
        'OFICINA',
        'USUARIO',
        'ROL',
        'PAGINAS',
    );

    $hoja->fromArray($cabecera_columna, NULL, 'A2');
    $hoja->setAutoFilter('A2:G2');
    $hoja->getStyle('A2:G2')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('BDD7EE');
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);

    $cont = 3;
    foreach ($lista as $obj) {


        $hoja->setCellValue('A' . $cont, $obj->apellidos);
        $hoja->setCellValue('B' . $cont, $obj->nombres);
        $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('C' . $cont, $obj->numdoc, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $hoja->setCellValue('D' . $cont, $obj->oficina);
        $hoja->setCellValue('E' . $cont, $obj->usuario);
        $hoja->setCellValue('F' . $cont, $obj->rol);
        $hoja->setCellValue('G' . $cont, $obj->permisos);

        $cont ++;
    }

    $date = new DateTime ();
    $date = $date->getTimestamp();
    $filename = 'REPORTE_USUARIOS_' . $date . '.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    ob_end_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Comment: que intentas hacer exactamente

Comment: Quitar ese error

Comment: si, lo se te entiendo pero que quieres exactamente, que necesitas que haga ese codigo que tienes

Comment: La funcion crea el excel, levantado en mi local corre al 100 descarga el excel pero lo subo a la nube y sale error

Comment: no disculpa no es eso, ya que dijiste que es en la nube

Comment: puede que al momento de subirlo no se este descargando el formato, bueno diria yo eso como por ejemplo el tipo de letra en negrita, el filtro, y el color

Comment: Lo raro es que tengo otros proyectos en ese mismo server que tienen para descargar en excel y no tienen ningun problema igual gracias por tu coementario

Comment: Ese error normalmente tiene que ver con que el formato del excel sea `.xslx` y la extension sea `.xsl`o  al reves

Comment: @Pikoh si tambien puede ser eso estas en lo correcto, olvide ese punto. +1

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores podrias mostrar la extencion de tus excels?

Comment: son `.xsl` pero por que si me levanta en el local y en server no?

Comment: .xsl? y porque lo tienes como .xls

Comment: que yo sepa es .xls

Comment: Amplio mi respuesta con un detalle más

Comment: El problema está encontrado. Es un archivo PHP que tiene BOM UTF-8. Estamos buscando cuál es, pero al no tener acceso shell al VPS ni usar linux el trabajo es lento.

Comment: Ivan: leer [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer) te puede ser útil. Eliminé la respuesta de la parte de pregunta y la añadí a la sección de respuestas, que es donden corresponden. Gracia

Comment: Me alegro que solucionaras tu problema. ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que has eliminado la marca de respuesta correcta a mi respuesta? Es una copia sacada de mi respuesta. ¿Por qué no has propuesto una modificación de mi respuesta una vez que has confirmado que con ella solucionaste el problema? @fedorqui si editó su pregunta para poner la solución es porque estuvimos largo y tendido trabajando en la búsqueda del problema en mi respuesta, no hay motivo para marcar otra respuesta como correcta si la mía fue la que dio con el problema y la solución.

Comment: @OscarGarcia entiendo tu malestar. Yo me limité a mover la respuesta a la zona donde corresponde, es decir, a las respuestas. Por el bien de la claridad en la exposición, una pregunta solo debe contener eso, la pregunta. Coincido contigo en que la respuesta aceptada debería ser la tuya si es la que ayudó, por lo que animo a Ivan a reconsiderar su decisión.

Comment: @OscarGarcia la [revisión 4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/72040/revisions) parece claramente una respuesta, no una edición. La pregunta plantea unas dudas, las respuestas ofrecen soluciones y ese texto no podía pertener a una pregunta. Fíjate que solamente sigo lo indicado en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), con la diferencia que publiqué yo (en modo wiki, no recibo beneficio alguno) para mostrárselo al autor y que lo sepa en el futuro. Claro está, no tengo ningún inonveniente en eliminarla, pero debe ser desaceptada para ello.

Comment: Ivan: @OscarGarcia indica con razón que la respuesta que pusiste en tu pregunta era casi la misma que él te mostró en su respuesta. Al verla allí, yo la moví a la sección de respuestas pues donde las respuestas deben estar para que todo esto sea más claro. Sin embargo, parece claro que lo que realmente ayudó a solucionar tu problema fue lo que Oscar indicó, por lo que sería bueno y bonito que aceptaras esa respuesta. La otra quedaría aún aquí, pero como referencia. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edición**

El problema ha sido detectado. El excel tiene al comienzo los caracteres de un archivo UTF-8 con [`BOM` (marca de orden de bytes)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes):

```
00000000  ef bb bf d0 cf 11 e0 a1  b1 1a e1 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

Los caracteres `ef bb bf` componen el BOM, lo que indica que uno de los archivos PHP lo usa, agregándose al comienzo del archivo excel generado, provocando que éste no esté correctamente formado.

Estamos trabajando para dar con el archivo y eliminar el BOM.

---

**Respuesta inicial**

Existen tres posibles causas de tu problema:

- Tu programa PHP empieza con un espacio en blanco o un [`BOM` (marca de orden de bytes)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes). Eso produce el envío de datos antes del excel (pone `_<?php`).
- El carácter que indicas suele producirse por el mismo problema anterior generado por un retorno del carro antes o después de alguna apertura o cierre de PHP en algún script que estés incluyendo (`<?php` o `?>`).
- En algún lado de tu código (antes de ejecutar `ob_start()`) se está lanzando un mensaje de advertencia (por ejemplo índice de una matriz no existente) inutilizando por ello el formato del excel que entregas.

Ya que no disponemos del código completo para averiguar dónde estás dejando ese carácter adicional, te recomiendo que revises concienzudamente cada apertura y cierre de PHP para comprobar que no haya ningún carácter ni salto de línea adicional (puedes usar un editor hexadecimal si te sientes cómodo manejándolos).

Usas un truco temporal con [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) y [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) que te ayuda a limpiar esos problemas entre ambos, pero deberías poner el `ob_start()` al comienzo del PHP, como primera línea de código. De ese modo podrás capturar cualquier mensaje desde el mismo comienzo de la ejecución del script PHP, no sólo dentro de esa función.

Es una función completamente inocua para cualquier otro funcionamiento habitual de PHP, por lo que puedes usarlo siempre que quieras con total libertad (aunque lo ideal es averiguar la causa raíz del problema).

Una vez que cambies el `ob_start()` al comienzo del código, como primera línea, modifica el final con esto para generarte un archivo con el mensaje de advertencia o caracteres adicionales que te están molestando:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
/* Obtenemos los caracteres adicionales o mensajes de advertencia y los
  guardamos en el archivo "depuracion.txt" si tenemos permisos */
file_put_contents('depuracion.txt', ob_get_contents());
/* Limpiamos el búfer */
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Ya modifique el codigo espero me ayude un poco mas

Comment: ¿Te sigue fallando? No sé si es un error al pegar el código, pero fíjate que hay un montón de espacios en blanco en el primer PHP antes del `<?php`. Quítalos todos.

Comment: te dejo mi archivo php, subido al drive, enserio llevo tiempo con esto y no lo puedo corregir, y lo peor q solo es en este proyecto es algo del codigo https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-h71-fJAWEdUHJuR3lHNFRUNzQ

Comment: En principio con el editor de textos de mi móvil no veo espacios, habrá sido un fallo al pegar el código en la pregunta. Pero veo que aún no has hecho las modificaciones que te recomendé. ¿Podrías probarlas y decirme qué tal fue con ellas?

Comment: el  `ond_start()`  esta bien ahi ?`<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
ob_start();`

Comment: ¿Te ha generado el archivo "depuracion.txt"? ¿Podrías pasarme el archivo excel para verlo con un editor hexadecimal? ¿Has revisado el resto de archivos php que se carguen antes que el tuyo? Recuerda que puedes usar `ob_start()` al principio del script. Si usas codeigniter, y todo pasa por el `index.php`, lo puedes agregar allí.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59129/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-ivan-more-flores).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59143/discussion-between-ivan-more-flores-and-oscargarcia).

Comment: necesito de ayuda :c

Comment: ¿Qué te ocurre? Intenté acceder al chat que abriste y parece borrado. El que abrí yo está congelado (no se puede usar). ¿Abro otro? Siento si tardo en responder, llevo un mes inactivo por aquí por trabajo y estudios.

Comment: si porfavor!!! :c

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61185/excel-fallido @OscarGarcia

Comment: ya lo cree te dejo descriccion ahi yo me tengo que ir a estudiar suerte entras al enlace de arriba

Answer (score 1):

<sub>La solución aportada por el autor de la pregunta en una [revisión de la propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/72040/revisions).</sub>

La solución consiste en:

Entrar a mi archivo `index.php` de mi controler (porque uso CI) que en mi caso era `inicio.php` colocar `ob_start()` despues del  `<?php` ; y luego en los otros controladores donde tenia una funcion de crear `excel` 
El siguiente codigo es el resultado final :

```
public function exportar_excel_usuarios() {


        set_time_limit(0);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
        $fecha_reporte = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $lista = null;
        $lista = $this->Usuario_model->listar_reporte();

        $this->load->library('excel');
        $hoja = $this->excel->getActiveSheet();
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $hoja->setTitle('ASUNTOS');
        $hoja->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE DE USUARIOS ' . $fecha_reporte);
        $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(24);
        $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $hoja->mergeCells('A1:G1');
        $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        $cabecera_columna = array(
            'APELLIDOS',
            'NOMBRES',
            'NUM. DOC.',
            'OFICINA',
            'USUARIO',
            'ROL',
            'PAGINAS',
        );

        $hoja->fromArray($cabecera_columna, NULL, 'A2');
        $hoja->setAutoFilter('A2:G2');
        $hoja->getStyle('A2:G2')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('BDD7EE');
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
        $hoja->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);

        $cont = 3;
        foreach ($lista as $obj) {


            $hoja->setCellValue('A' . $cont, $obj->apellidos);
            $hoja->setCellValue('B' . $cont, $obj->nombres);
            $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('C' . $cont, $obj->numdoc, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $hoja->setCellValue('D' . $cont, $obj->oficina);
            $hoja->setCellValue('E' . $cont, $obj->usuario);
            $hoja->setCellValue('F' . $cont, $obj->rol);
            $hoja->setCellValue('G' . $cont, $obj->permisos);

            $cont ++;
        }

        $date = new DateTime ();
        $date = $date->getTimestamp();
        $filename = 'REPORTE_USUARIOS_' . $date . '.xls';

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
        /* Obtenemos los caracteres adicionales o mensajes de advertencia y los
          guardamos en el archivo "depuracion.txt" si tenemos permisos */
        file_put_contents('depuracion.txt', ob_get_contents());
        /* Limpiamos el búfer */
        ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error aparece simplemente porque estás estableciendo el formato de Excel como Excel5 y estás usando una extensión .xls

Debes establecer la extensión como .xlsx

```
$filename = 'REPORTE_USUARIOS_' . $date . '.xlsx';
```

Edito, no me había fijado en que tienes definido el content type.

Para las versiones de Excel a partir de 2007, el content type correcto es el siguiente

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

Y como prueba final, en lugar de Excel5 utiliza el writer para Excel 2007:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pueden salir estos mensajes de error tambien si

a) Hay errores de compilación en partes que no son cabeceras.

b) Las cabeceras están ANTES del contenido.

Prueben a comentar todo el contenido y dejar solo las cabeceras para comprobar si el error persiste. 
Este mensaje de error puede haceros dar muchas vueltas pensando en los tipos de datos cuando no tienen a veces nada que ver con el problema real

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema con un proyecto docker.
Mire foro e intente propuestas que habian en aquellos foros y sin resultado positivo.
Luego mire la documentación de la librería y esta indicaba los requisitos a tener en el PHP, y era el tener instalada una extesiones para el php.

#Estas extesione son las que funciona para exportar un excel y el archivo no quede corupto
#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y 
libzip-dev 
zip 
&& docker-php-ext-install zip